# Delete triples with exceptions

Tags: sparql

I want to delete all triples of an URI. All but those with the `rdf:type` property.

Something like:

```
DELETE DATA { <myUri> ?p ?o.
              NOT <myUri> rdf:type ?o }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `DELETE-WHERE` form.

```
DELETE { <myUri> ?p ?o }
WHERE  { <myUri> ?p ?o.
         FILTER(?p != rdf:type) }
```